# opening a ROR directory in terminal then start rails server

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, terminal

im really new to ruby and ROR and im having real trouble trying to get my directory that i created earlier to open in terminal (on a mac) and then start the rails server so i can preview it in the browser.

ive been trying :

`cd /Users/sam/Documents/Pudle/Projects/treeb`

and

`ruby /Users/sam/Documents/Pudle/Projects/treeb`

then running `rails s`

i think the problem im having is that im not loading in the directory correctly, appologies for it being such a simple question but ive been going round in circles with this for hours !
any helps much appreciated

Comment: What's exactly the error when you try running 'rails s'?

Comment: its not an error as such its just the instuctions of how to use rails s - this one : Usage:
  rails new APP_PATH [options]

Options:
  -r, [--ruby=PATH]              # Path to the Ruby binary of your choice
                                 # Default: /usr/local/rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.3-p194/bin/ruby
  -b, [--builder=BUILDER]        # Path to a application builder (can be a filesystem path or URL)
  -m, [--template=TEMPLATE]      # Path to an appl.......

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you've created your new Rails application using `rails new app_name`, you can simply start the server by running `cd /Users/sam/Documents/Pudle/Projects/treeb` and `rails s`

Answer (score 0):

Ref [`how to create a rails application`](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/getting_started.html#creating-the-blog-application)

suppose your application path is `cd /Users/sam/Documents/Pudle/Projects/treeb`

then do following to start the server

```
cd /Users/sam/Documents/Pudle/Projects/treeb
rails server #or just rails s
```

NOTE:- Above will work only if you are using Rails 3

For Rails 2

```
ruby script/server
```

Comment: thanks i think i found what was stopping it, if i ran rvm before i start the rails server it worked

Comment: nice, just remember to set a default for rvm, so you don't have to run rvm everytime.